# MongoDB .NET: Mapping inherited generic property

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, generics, inheritance

I have a generic class `Parameter` with a generic property `Value`:

```
abstract class Parameter<T> {
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

`StringParameter` class inherits the `Parameter` class:

```
class StringParameter : Parameter<string> {
    //...
}
```

Is it possible to properly map the `StringParameter` class so that it contains the generic `Value` property?

When trying to map the `StringParameter` class with the code below (and various other approaches) the best I could do is get an exception with the message: "The memberInfo argument must be for class StringParameter, but was for class Parameter`1."

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<StringParameter>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapMember(typeof(StringParameter).GetRuntimeProperty("Value"));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping the `Parameter` class with the specified type parameter for every subclass that inherits it and then automapping each subclass seems to have done the trick.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Parameter<string>>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapProperty("Value");
});
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Parameter<DateTime>>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapProperty("Value");
});
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Parameter<int>>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapProperty("Value");
});
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Parameter<decimal>>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapProperty("Value");
});

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<StringParameter>();
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<DateParameter>();
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<IntegerParameter>();
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<DecimalParameter>();
```

Note that this maps all the `Parameter` classes into  a single collection with appropriate discriminators.